# How to use model scopes in a custom module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

In my model I have define the scope:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :accessible_for, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }
end
```

In controller it works perfectly:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    @operations = MyModel.accessible_for current_user
  end

end
```

I`d like to use it in a custom module

```
module Reports
  class ReportMyModel

    def do_export(user)
      to_export = MyModel.accessible_for user
    end

  end
end
```

Unfortunatelly, I receive an error after call "do_export"

```
undefined method `accessible_for' for <Class:0x000000065396d8>
```

So, how can I use it correctly?

Comment: Your scope is named `accesible_for` with a single `s`.  You have a typo!

Comment: oh, it`s just a typo in question! Scope defined as scope :accessible_for, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }

Comment: Also, it works correctly, when I call `do_export` from Rails console...

Answer (score 0):

After successfully run this code on another workstation, I rebooted my computer and everything became well. So, there were not any mistakes in code.